# HTMl5 + JS auto video playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/arvnnxpw/

Ok so the js code when it gets to the last video it just stops instead of returning to the first one, how do I fix this?

I've tried multiple ways and I just can't get it to return to the first video after the last one is played.

```
$(function() {
var $videos = $("#playlist li");
var $video = $("#videoarea");
var current = 0;
var max = 1;

function playVideo(video) {
    current = elIndex($videos, video);
    if (!current) {
        return false;
    }
    $video.attr({
        "src": $(video).attr("movieurl"),
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
}

$video.attr({
    "src": $videos.eq(current).attr("movieurl"),
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
})

$video.on('ended', function () {
  if (current == max) {
        playVideo($videos[0]);
    } else {
                playVideo($videos[current + 1]);
    }
});

function elIndex(parent, el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i += 1) {
        if (parent[i] === el) {
          return i;   
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
if (!current) {
    return false;
}
```

Because when it tries to play the first one again `current = 0` so `!current`returns true. If you change that if for `if(current == undefined)`, everything is ok.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arvnnxpw/1/) works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this part?

```
if (!current) {
    return false;
}
```

If you remove it, it works.
When the playback would start all over again from the first video, current will be `0`, `0` coerces to `false`, `!false` will become `true` and the `playVideo` just returns `false`.